# In Robot framework, how can I execute test cases using data driver with multiple excel sheets

Tags: testing, robotframework

```
'''

    Library  DataDriver  abcd.xlsx sheet_name=Sheet1
    Library  DataDriver  abcd.xlsx sheet_name=Sheet2
'''
```

This not working for me. Only one sheet gets executed. Can I use multiple excel sheets?

Comment: I don't think that is possible, why are you trying to use multiple excel sheets? U can just paste the rows of the second sheet in the first one since the arguments must be exactly the same.

Comment: @Ruben Thanks for your input. Actually the arguments in the second sheet is entirely different. First test case is using first sheet with a set of arguments and second test case which is entirely different from first is using another set of arguments. But for the second case, I am not able to use data driver.

Answer (score 0):

Datadriver can only read 1 excel sheet and use it to perform 1 template (which can run as many testcases as you want in that template).
If you want to use multiple excel sheets and multiple templates, you'll have to make multiple test suites. Each test suite will consist of 1 excel sheet and 1 template for datadriver.